# Objective-C and designing a plugin mechanism

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, plugins

I need to design a simple plugin system in Objective C.  I would like some advice about how to go about this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa is your girlfriend: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/17/cocoa-tutorial-adding-plugins-to-a-cocoa-application/

Awesome tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is always going to the Source. Here is the [ADC reference to Plug-ins](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/CFPlugIns.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways you could do this, so you might need to elaborate a little on what exactly you're trying to achieve. As a starting point, I'd recommend you look into Cocoa delegates which are usually a great way to integrate new code into an existing framework.